# Formatting numbers for commas and decimal places with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function with javascript that displays all numbers with two decimal points and adds commas every three digits (1,000 10,000 100,000 etc).

At first I had this:

```
var formatNumber = function(num) {
    return parseFloat((num).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString();
};
```

This works very well but with one exception.

1.2 != 1.20 in the final output.  It just shows up as 1.2

But everything else is good.  124.5879697 = 124.59, 10000 = 10,000, and 10586.357 = 10,586.36

The issue is the final output is going to display as money, so displaying 10000 as $10,000 is fine.  But displaying 1.2 as $1.2 looks a little off.

To get around this I tried to add the following modification:

```
var formatNumber = function(num) {
   return parseFloat((Math.round(num*100)/100)).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
};
```

This carries everything out to two decimal places, which is fine, but it seems to have de-activated toLocaleString because now nothing displays commas.

I'm looking to use pure Javascript with this and not jQuery.  It seems there are a lot of js questions on this topic about one or the other issue, but not combining both.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you test to see how many numbers are after the decimal, and if its only one, add a 0 to the end of it?

Comment: try this regex to append 0 if single digit after decimal:
`parseFloat((num).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString().replace(/\.([0-9])$/, ".$10")`

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work

```
var formatNumber = function(num) {
    return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work for whole numbers.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/razs3mjb/)

Comment: @KenGregory No desire to be a necromancer but you placed `toFixed()` inside `parseFloat()` in your fiddle and that's why it failed for you. If you move it outside, it works fine, and you can also do away with the `replace`. [Forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j95hroy/).

Comment: @DanAtkinson thanks!  My overdue apologies to Katya Pavlenko - I was wrong here.

Comment: I ran into issues with this approach because .toFixed() will turn your number into a string and then running toLocaleString() on that doesn't have the desired effect of adding the commas. I found the approach in this answer worked well though. Just adding in case others run into a similiar issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48653557/402780