# .toLocaleString() not showing commas on numbers with decimals

Tags: javascript

`.toLocaleString()` works great on my integer data types; however, it isn't working for numbers with decimals.

I have some large currency numbers that I divide by 1000 to present in thousands and `.toFixed(1)` decimals spot. So `1315321.56` becomes `1315.3`. What I have is this:

```
<td>${(fieldObj/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
```

When I tried to add `.toLocaleString()` with the intent of it rendering `1,315.3` nothing happens and it just displays it as normal. How can I get around this?

To be clear, this is what I have with it added:

```
<td>${(fieldObj/1000).toFixed(1).toLocaleString()}</td>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a "string representing the given number using fixed-point notation" and not a number, so you can't call `toLocaleString` on the result

You can use the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) options to round to 1 digit.

```
(1315321.56/1000).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1})
"1,315.3"
```

Comment: That does seem to work; however, it is now dropping trailing `.0` from numbers that don't have a decimal. I'll figure that out.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the `minimumFractionDigits: 1` option as well